# Modem/router that can handle 50+ clients

Tags: networking, router, internet, modem

I have a network of 50+ PCs, with a Dynalink RTA 1320 for internet access, and have issues with internet speed. The Dynalink connects with a PPPoA connection.

Only about 20 actually have internet access (the rest have the gateway manually removed...), and of course they aren't actually accessing the internet all the time. There are internet slowness issues though, and I suspect the Dynalink is balking, it being a consumer grade modem/router.

So I've been looking into a business grade modem/router, but my googlefoo seems to be failing me. I've heard of Zyxel before, but what are some other alternatives?

Update: I went with the Draytek recommendation, and it has been very solid.

Comment: What is the bandwidth on your line right now ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First thing to do is check your network usage.  If 10 of those 50 PCs are each trying to max out the broadband connection with bittorrent or youtube, then no amount of tinkering with hardware will get away from the overzealous demand.  Make the users take bandwidth seriously.

On the hardware side, the first thing you should probably try is putting a switch in front of the modem/router, so that nothing is connected to the router except the switch.  The switch should be able to decide what to bug the router about.

Failing that, it's time to look at an "SME-class" broadband router -- Draytek are a quality manufacturer of routers, and should have some product to suit you.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I have checked the two things you mentioned previously, but I will do a more thorough check before I move further.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be a Cisco Modem/Router something like the 1700 series.  I assume your using an ADSL connection in which case the 1700 would be fine.

I have to say we used Zyxel equipment a couple of years ago - it is all available on Ebay at the moment !

If your not happy working on Cisco equipment then I agree with Lee B.  There are plenty of other GUI based Modem Routers out there just look at memory and throughput first to decide on what you want.